# Bash file doesnt work when it is launched from ruby script, but works with the same entry manually

Tags: ruby, string, bash

I have a very strange situation. I have a command in some ruby script, which launches a bash file with some parameters.

It looks like this in ruby

```
 res=`/usr/bin/some-file #{script_options}`
```

And there is some strange behavior. If `script_options` includes some russian symbols, bash script doesn't working

But if I launch bash script manually from command line with exactly `script-options`, all works properly.

Do you have any ideas what it could be, or should I update this question and show some code examples?

***EDIT***

part of ruby code:

```
def restore_backup(id, options)
        script_options="#{id}"
        if options[:datastoreid]
            script_options="#{script_options} -d #{options[:datastoreid]}"
        end
        if options[:name]
            script_options="#{script_options} -n \"#{options[:name]}\""
        end

        err=0
        File.write('/opt/restore_script_opt', script_options)
        res=`/usr/bin/one-restorevm #{script_options}`
        if !$?.success?
            err=1
        end
        puts res
        return err
    end
```

So, this is how function defined. But if `script_options` contains some russian symbols like

`18 -d 1 -n "лштнфум"`, bash script launched by this function doesn't work

If I run it from command line, like

`one-restorevm 18 -d 1 -n "лштнфум"`

all is working.
Also, if the script is launched by this function with only English symbols - all is also working

Thank you

Comment: In what encoding is the ruby script saved? What's the locale setting of your command line shell and the shell running the command from ruby?

Comment: I dont know, how can I look it?

Comment: By the way I think it is also essential - in the same ruby file there is almost the same function, which launches another bash file, and second file works properly from ruby with russian entrance

Comment: *includes some russian symbols* like what? Please give an example

Comment: _doesn't working_ isn't exactly a helpful description of the problem. Unless you can provide a minimal reproducible example, I don't see how you could get help here.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: See https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Encoding.html and possibly https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellwords. It's likely an encoding or splitting issue, but without a lot more detail you probably won't get much help.

Comment: When I use only English symbols, the `script_options.encoding=UTF-8`, when russian or mixed - `ASCII-8BIT`